# Excel 2002 XML Spreadsheet - validation trouble

Tags: excel, xml, validation, excel-2003

I am creating Excel sheets in the somewhat ancient 2003 SpreadsheetML flavour (mainly because everything is contained in one single file). Trying to implement a selection list drives my crazy - either due to my stupidity or to a lack of documentation.

Have a look at this (works nicely with recent versions of Excel):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Worksheet ss:Name="input">
                <ss:Table>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"/></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Anna</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Berta</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Claudia</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                </ss:Table>
                <DataValidation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                        <Range>R1C1</Range>
                        <Type>List</Type>
                        <Value>input!R2</Value>
                </DataValidation>
        </Worksheet>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="check">
                <ss:Table>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"/></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Alfred</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Bruno</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Clemens</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                </ss:Table>
        </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Two worksheets containing a list of names in Row 2, plus one single cell with a simple validation rule: input!A1 may only contain one of the names "Anna", "Berta" or "Claudia". Works as expected.

But then I change the validation to what I actually want to achieve (i.e. use the list from the other worksheet):

```
<Value>check!R2</Value>
```

This still loads into Excel, but there is no dropdown. If I look at the validation rules, Excel claims a "reference error" (or similar - I am using German locales), even though I cannot find any error in "check!R2". I can correct this manually to check!$2:$2 (the UI way of cell referencing), I can save the result into an XML file, and the result is exactly the "check!R2" which I tried without success...

But as soon as I open the (saved) file, the reference is invalid again.

This drives me nuts - there must be *some* way to validate against values from another worksheet. Unfortunately there is not too much documentation available (and actually never has been); one of my sources is https://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/Office/2003/?page=excelss_xsd.html which lists all the available tags but not the details of their semantics.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: In older versions of Excel, you couldn't use a direct reference to another worksheet as a DV list source; you had to use a named range. Perhaps that is related?

Comment: I don't think Rory is correct with Excel 2003 especially with you manually being able to get it working  Maybe Rory is referring to excel versions before 2003. Excel workbooks sometimes get internal errors and the only way of fixing is to open a new workbook and then copy the worksheet from old workbook to new workbook.  I've seen this happen more with excel 2003 than new versions of excel.  It is worth trying.

Comment: In 2003 and prior you could not use a DV list source on another worksheet directly. That changed in 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That old 2003 `XML` schema should be avoided. But if used, then one can only use features which were available in year 2003 too. So @Rory is correct in his comments. In 2003 `Excel` was not able getting data validation lists from other sheets directly. Named ranges had must be created which refers to the other sheet. And those `Name`s then had been referenced by the datavalidation list.

So following will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Names>
                <NamedRange ss:Name="ceckRow2" ss:RefersTo="=check!R2"/>
        </Names>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="input">
                <ss:Table>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"/></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Anna</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Berta</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Claudia</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                </ss:Table>
                <DataValidation xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                        <Range>R1C1</Range>
                        <Type>List</Type>
                        <Value>ceckRow2</Value>
                </DataValidation>
        </Worksheet>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="check">
                <ss:Table>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String"/></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                        <ss:Row>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Alfred</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Bruno</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                                <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Clemens</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
                        </ss:Row>
                </ss:Table>
        </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did not expect that Excel saves something that looks perfectly reasonable - but is not. With the NamedRange everything works fine.
Bonus question: Which else format to use? I am not aware of anything combining data, styles, and formulas into a single file (which makes generation *so* much easier).

Comment: @SlowFox: "I did not expect that Excel saves something that looks perfectly reasonable - but is not.": Well it warns that features might get lost. Amd that is often the case then. Do saving and then always do reopening the currently saved and check.

Comment: @SlowFox: There is not a `XML` schema which could be able describing all possible features of an `Excel` workbook. That's why `Office Open XML` (`*.xlsx`) is a `ZIP` archive containing **multiple** `XML` files and other files too.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll stay with this format. I use it to provide customers with simple, but still good-looking reports and forms for data-entry. I could not justify the efforts creating an xlsx (not mentioning the efforts understanding this monster).